# How can I fix ngx-bootstrap "can't resolve" errors

Tags: ngx-bootstrap

I have a new project that I am trying to add ngx-bootstrap to.

if I include below import into any component

```
import { BsModalRef } from 'ngx-bootstrap';
```

I get a ton of compile errors as follows...

> ERROR in C:/Source/MappingServices/node_modules/ngx-bootstrap/collapse/fesm2015/ngx-bootstrap-collapse.js
> Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '@angular/animations' in 'C:\Source\MappingServices\node_modules\ngx-bootstrap\collapse\fesm2015'
> ERROR in C:/Source/MappingServices/node_modules/ngx-bootstrap/buttons/fesm2015/ngx-bootstrap-buttons.js
> Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '@angular/forms' in 'C:\Source\MappingServices\node_modules\ngx-bootstrap\buttons\fesm2015'
> ERROR in C:/Source/MappingServices/node_modules/ngx-bootstrap/datepicker/fesm2015/ngx-bootstrap-datepicker.js
> Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '@angular/forms' in 'C:\Source\MappingServices\node_modules\ngx-bootstrap\datepicker\fesm2015'
> ERROR in C:/Source/MappingServices/node_modules/ngx-bootstrap/pagination/fesm2015/ngx-bootstrap-pagination.js
> Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '@angular/forms' in 'C:\Source\MappingServices\node_modules\ngx-bootstrap\pagination\fesm2015'
> ERROR in C:/Source/MappingServices/node_modules/ngx-bootstrap/rating/fesm2015/ngx-bootstrap-rating.js
> Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '@angular/forms' in 'C:\Source\MappingServices\node_modules\ngx-bootstrap\rating\fesm2015'
> ERROR in C:/Source/MappingServices/node_modules/ngx-bootstrap/sortable/fesm2015/ngx-bootstrap-sortable.js
> Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '@angular/forms' in 'C:\Source\MappingServices\node_modules\ngx-bootstrap\sortable\fesm2015'
> ERROR in C:/Source/MappingServices/node_modules/ngx-bootstrap/timepicker/fesm2015/ngx-bootstrap-timepicker.js
> Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '@angular/forms' in 'C:\Source\MappingServices\node_modules\ngx-bootstrap\timepicker\fesm2015'
> ERROR in C:/Source/MappingServices/node_modules/ngx-bootstrap/typeahead/fesm2015/ngx-bootstrap-typeahead.js
> Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '@angular/forms' in 'C:\Source\MappingServices\node_modules\ngx-bootstrap\typeahead\fesm2015'

I've search for a solution but there is none that works for me.
Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: did you import the ModalModule like explained at https://valor-software.com/ngx-bootstrap/#/modals ?

Comment: yes, I've used this library in other applications and have always followed the ng-bootstrap usage instructions

Answer (score 0):

not sure why npm isnt installing dependencies in ur setup
try installing packages which you see in the error

- https://www.npmjs.com/package/@angular/forms
- @angular/animations